# How to skip printing the command output and just get the return value from a os.system command?

Tags: python, os.system

Consider the following examples -

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan 14 2011, 00:20:04)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system("grep -i beatles blur.txt")
Blur's debut album Leisure (1991) incorporated the sounds of Madchester and shoegazing. Following a stylistic change.influenced by English guitar pop groups such as The Kinks, The Beatles and XTC.
0
>>> os.system("grep -i metallica blur.txt")
256
>>>
```

So, in this case, I don't want the line having my searched keyword to be printed on the Python shell, I just want the return value i.e. 0 if keyword is present and non-zero if its not. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use `-q` key of the `grep`:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3rc2 (default, Apr  5 2012, 18:58:12) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system("grep -iq igor /etc/passwd")
0
>>> os.system("grep -iq oleg /etc/passwd")
256
>>>
```

I must note that `-q` is not portable key of the `grep`, it will work only with GNU grep (Linux and so on).

When you want to make it work on all systems, you must use `popen`/`subprocess.Popen` and redirections of streams.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> null = open(os.devnull, "w")
>>> grep = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("grep -i oleg /etc/passwd"), stderr = null, stdout = null)
>>> grep.communicate()
(None, None)
>>> print grep.returncode
1
>>> grep = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("grep -i igor /etc/passwd"), stderr = null, stdout = null)
>>> grep.communicate()
(None, None)
>>> print grep.returncode
0
```

Comment: What is `null` supposed to be here?

Comment: @F.J: sorry, I've missed a string. Thank you for the tip, added the string now.

Comment: `os.system`, `.communicate` are unnecessary in this case, see F.J.'s answer

Answer (score 1):

Igor Chubin's answer is a good one, but the simplest answer in your case may be just to redirect the output via the shell (since os.system is going to invoke a shell anyway, you may as well use it.)

```
os.system("grep -i beatles blur.txt > /dev/null 2>&1")
```

Answer (score 1):

For the generic question of "how do I prevent `os.system()`  output from being printed", the best way to do this is to use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, which is the recommended way to run external programs and it provides straightforward output redirection.

Here is how this might look for your example:

```
import os
import subprocess

devnull = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
subprocess.call('grep -i beatles blur.txt', stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull, shell=True)
```

The `shell=True` option means that that the program will be executed through the shell, which is what `os.system()` does, but it is better (safer) to drop the `shell=True` and pass a list with the command arguments.

```
subprocess.call(['grep', '-i', 'beatles', 'blur.txt'], stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
```

Comment: +1 almost there. Use 'wb' mode. Pass a list instead of a string and drop `shell=True`. Use returned value from `call`. You could also specify `stderr=STDOUT`